# VBA para pesquisa de pastas e concatenar nomes de ficheiros

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, concatenação-de-string

Preciso de evoluir o seguinte código para fazer a concatenação de dados de certa forma.
Tenho uma pasta com fotos de produtos, (varias fotos para cada produto) e pretendo que o Excel faça uma busca pelo nome das fotos e escreva os nomes das fotos referentes a cada produto numa célula e separados por uma virgula.

Outra questão é que para cada produto as fotos podem ter diferentes extensões ou seja, pode ter **JPG** e/ou **PNG** e/ou **JPEG**. (ver exemplos)

O nome das fotos é o mesmo que a referencia do produto e caso o produto tenha mais de uma foto o nome é diferenciado por uma letra do alfabeto no fim do nome e antes do ponto e da extensão.
Ex: ac2345**a**.jpg ou 023198AA**b**.jpg ou GDV7YDX**c**.jpeg
O nome pode ser apenas números, ou apenas letras ou um mix de números e letras.

Outra condição é que para existir uma imagem ac2345**a**.jpg tem de existir uma imagem ac2345.jpg(ou png ou jpeg), para existir uma imagem GDV7YDX**c**.jpeg tem de existir uma imagem GDV7YDX.jpg(ou png ou jpeg), uma imagem GDV7YDX**a**.jpg(ou png ou jpeg) e uma imagem GDV7YDX**b**.jpg(ou png ou jpeg).

No total podem existir 1000, 2000, 3000 fotos ou mais na pasta e para cada produto podem existir 1 ou 2 ou 3 ou 15, etc. fotos

### Exemplo

- FOTOS do produto ac2345

  - ac2345.png
  - ac2345a.jpg
  - ac2345b.png
- FOTOS do produto 106

  - 106.jpeg
  - 106a.jpg
  - 106b.jpg
  - 106c.jpg
  - 106d.jpg
- FOTOS do produto 023198AA

  - 023198AA.png
  - 023198AAa.png
  - 023198AAb.jpg
- FOTOS do produto GDV7YDX

  - GDV7YDX.png
  - GDV7YDXa.png
  - GDV7YDXb.jpg
  - GDV7YDXc.jpeg
  - GDV7YDXd.jpg
  - GDV7YDXe.png

### Código

O código que apresento faz a procura de todos os ficheiros existentes numa pasta e escreve os nomes dos ficheiros numa folha mas escreve cada nome numa célula em separado e todos na coluna A.

Exemplo:

> Celula A1 = ac2345.png
>
> Celula A2 = ac2345a.jpg
>
> Celula A3 = ac2345b.png
>
> Célula A4 = 106.jpeg
>
> Célula A5 = 106a.jpg
>
> Célula A6 = 106b.jpg
>
> Célula A7 = 106c.jpg
>
> Célula A8 = 106d.jpg
>
> Célula A9 = 023198AA.png
>
> Célula A10 = 023198AAa.png
>
> Célula A11 = 023198AAb.jpg
>
> Célula A12 = GDV7YDX.png
>
> Célula A13 = GDV7YDXa.png
>
> Célula A14 = GDV7YDXb.jpg
>
> Célula A15 = GDV7YDXc.jpeg
>
> Célula A16 = GDV7YDXd.jpg
>
> Célula A17 = GDV7YDXe.png

### Problema

O que eu preciso é que na mesma célula fiquem os nomes referentes a cada produto separados por virgula.

Exemplo:

> Celula A1 = ac2345.png, ac2345a.jpg, ac2345b.png
>
> Celula A2 = 106.jpeg, 106a.jpg, 106b.jpg, 106c.jpg, 106d.jpg
>
> Celula A3 = 023198AA.png, 023198AAa.png, 023198AAb.jpg
>
> Celula A4 = GDV7YDX.png, GDV7YDXa.png, GDV7YDXb.jpg, GDV7YDXc.jpeg, GDV7YDXd.jpg, GDV7YDXe.png

Eis o código que tenho:

```
Sub GetJPGandPNGandJPEG()    
   Dim X As Long, LastDot As Long, Path As String, FileName As String, F(0 To 9) As String
   Path = "C:\teste\"
   FileName = Dir(Path & "*.*p*g")
   Do While Len(FileName)
      LastDot = InStrRev(FileName, ".")
   If LCase(Mid(FileName, LastDot)) = ".jpg" Or LCase(Mid(FileName, LastDot)) = ".png" Or LCase(Mid(FileName, LastDot)) = ".jpeg" Then
      If Left(FileName, 1) Like "#" Then
         F(Left(FileName, 1)) = F(Left(FileName, 1)) & ", " & FileName
      End If
   End If

   FileName = Dir
   Loop
      For X = 0 To 9
         Cells(X + 1, "A").Value = Mid(F(X), 3)
      Next
      Range("A1:A10").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).Delete

End Sub
```

Será que alguem me pode ajudar? Agradeço desde já a todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode referenciar a biblioteca Micrsoft Scripting Runtime para fazer uso aos objetos da File System Object(FSO), conforme o exemplo [aqui](http://www.tomasvasquez.com.br/blog/microsoft-office/vba-listar-arquivos-de-um-diretorio). Desta forma irá trabalhar com todos os arquivos que estão no diretório, a partir do laço do resultado dos arquivos, faça a comparação com o nome do produto, caso for, concatene o resultado, só vá para a próxima linha se for outro produto.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica Paulo mas não sou tão bom assim em VBA. Como faço para fazer referencia a biblioteca Micrsoft Scripting Runtime e em que sitio faço essa referencia.

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um exemplo baseado no seu (sem referenciar a biblioteca que mencionei):

```
Sub GetJPGandPNGandJPEG()

Dim Path As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim LastDot As Long
Dim FileNameAux As String
Dim FileNameConc As String
Dim LastRow As Long

Path = "C:\Temp\Imagens\"
FileName = Dir(Path & "*.*p*g")

Do While Len(FileName)
  LastDot = InStrRev(FileName, ".")
  If LCase(Mid(FileName, LastDot)) = ".jpg" Or LCase(Mid(FileName, LastDot)) = ".png"  Or LCase(Mid(FileName, LastDot)) = ".jpeg" Then
    If (FileNameAux = vbNullString) Then
      FileNameAux = Replace(FileName, LCase(Mid(FileName, LastDot)), "")
    End If

    If (InStr(1, FileName, FileNameAux, vbTextCompare)) Then
      If (FileNameConc = vbNullString) Then
      FileNameConc = FileName
    Else
      FileNameConc = FileNameConc & ", " & FileName
    End If
  Else
    If (FileNameConc = vbNullString) Then
      FileNameConc = FileName
    End If
    LastRow = Plan1.Cells(Plan1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Plan1.Cells(LastRow, 1) = FileNameConc
    FileNameAux = Replace(FileName, LCase(Mid(FileName, LastDot)), "")
    FileNameConc = FileName
  End If
End If
FileName = Dir
Loop
LastRow = Plan1.Cells(Plan1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Plan1.Cells(LastRow, 1) = FileNameConc
End Sub
```

O resultado ficou assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Paulo fui pesquisar e ja tinha feito a referencia a biblioteca... O resultado que apresenta é precisamente o que pretendia.. mas depois de ter copiado o seu codigo ele da erro 424  na linha "LastRow = Plan1.Cells(Plan1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1" o mais certo e ser erro meu ... eheheh

Comment: entretanto experimentei com a a referencia a biblioteca e sem e da sempre erro... sera que falta fazer alguma referencia a outra biblioteca que o paulo tenha no seu excel? peço desculpa se disser alguma barbaridade mas como já disse sou um nabo em vba... obrigado pela sua disponibilidade

Comment: Essa instrução aparece em 2 lugares no código, o erro ocorreu em qual delas?

Comment: na primeira referencia... pensei ate que seria por ter a minha folha como Folha1 e nao Plan1 e mudei o nome da minha folha para Plan1 mas continua a dar erro.

Comment: ja deu certissimooooooooo... fiz ao contrario e mudei Plan1 do codigo para Folha1 e esta a funcionar na perfeição...

Comment: que bom, qualquer coisa troque essa instrução por esta: LastRow = Worksheets("Nome da sua sheet").Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row + 1

Comment: Paulo muito obrigado pela ajuda.. fico-lhe eternamente grato pela sua disponibilidade.

Comment: ok... ficarei com essa informação... Obrigado mais uma vez..

Comment: Não esqueça de marcar como respondida!

Comment: como faço isso? ja procurei em todo o lado e nao vejo como marcar como respondida.

Comment: Já está marcada, obrigado!